# How can I fix this weird line that comes with Boostrap model when having two div with col-lg-6 ?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have a boostrap model , I see a weird line in it when having two divs with col-lg-6.  Can you please tell me why and help me to fix it ?

This is the model code

```
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Create</h4>
        </div>
        <form method="post" id="insert_form">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Code">Code</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Code" name="Code" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="CanSale">Sale</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CanSale" name="CanSale" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Barcode">Barcode</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Barcode" name="Barcode" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Code">Descriptoin</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Description" name="Description" />
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

below image red arrows shows the weird line that i am talking about. Please help me fix it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I forget to place "col" divs inside  `<div class="row">.`

I got it fixed by nesting "`col-lg-6"` divs inside `<div class="row"> </div>`